# Как создать ветку в discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

**Как создать ветку в discord.py?**

[image: -]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите это сделать с помощью текстовой команды, то вот:

```
@bot.command()
async def create_thread(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.create_thread(#arguments)
```

Подробнее о том, какие аргументы принимает функция `create_thread` можете почитать тут:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=create_thread#discord.TextChannel.create_thread

Comment: Можно уточнить, эта команда создаст ветку в сообщении с командой?

Comment: Она создаст ветку в канале, где было отправлено сообщение